# How to unset values in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

I use google analytics for websites and mobile apps.
Sometimes i send some custom dimensions

```
var dimensionValue = 'SOME_DIMENSION_VALUE';
ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue);
```

After some user actions i want to unset this values, how it can be done?

Answer (score 4):

You can't really unset dimensions.

If your dimensions are hit-scoped you do not need to, they only pertain to the interactions following the set calls on the same page.

If your dimensions are session-scoped only the last value is stored, so "unsetting" them would be the same as not setting them at all.  There is no real unset mechanism.

If your dimensions are user-scoped then you can change the value, but not remove it.

So GA does not have a real "unset" mechanism. The usual workaround is to define a "neutral" value and send that when to other value applies, but you still need to think of the scope restrictions mentioned above.

Comment: I use them to identify users, so i want to make users able to login and logout. But also i want to track users that are not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually send the values without setting'em in your datalayer by attaching it after the rest of event fields

```
var mydata = {
  dimesion3: 'hello',
  dimension5: 'world'
};
ga('myproperty.send','event','category','action','label','value',mydata);
```

If you don't actually want to set some of the above fields just remove them.

```
ga('myproperty.send','event','category','action',mydata);
```